# Trigger a specific stage from a GitLab pipeline with another GitLab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I need to specify the stage instead of triggering the whole thing. This is how it's currently configured.

```
stage: bridge
trigger:
   project: user/project2
   branch: master
   strategy: depend
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify variables in the parent pipeline which you can check in the child pipeline and specify the job creation via [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules). In the below example only `job1` is run as only the variable `$FOO` is set in the parent pipeline.

You parent pipeline:

```
test:
  stage: test
  variables:
    FOO: bar
  trigger:
    project: user/project2
    branch: master
    strategy: depend
```

Your child pipeline can look like this:

```
stages:
 - job1
 - job2

job1:
  stage: job1
  script:
    - echo "job1"
  rules:
    - if: '$FOO'

job2:
  stage: job2
  script: 
    - echo "job2"
  rules:
    - if: '$BAR'
```